# "Post your Question" is not available for clicking

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

I‘ve tried to post this question and at the last step, the <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd> button is not clickable, and there is no warning. What could be the problem?

Question:

> I want to download several PDF from an URL that automatically triggers
>   the download of the PDF. Then read the text and put into a data frame.
>
> The problem is I can not read the PDF once I have downloaded it.
>
> I have tried requesting and then reading it but it shows the following
>   error:
>
> ```
> "ValueError: embedded null character"
> ```
>
> I think it is because there is something wrong with the automatically
>   downloaded PDF.
>
> In your browser try this link and it will download a PDF as soon as
>   you press Enter:
>
> https://soa.afip.gob.ar/sr-padron/v1/constancia/30500010912
>
> My code is:
>
> ```
> import requests as rq import PyPDF2 as pfr
>
> body =
> rq.get('https://soa.afip.gob.ar/sr-padron/v1/constancia/30500010912',
> 'rb') pdf_obj = pfr.PdfFileReader(body.text)
> ```
>
> I use the attribute *.text* to access de PDF, if not I have a text:
>   *Response [200]*
>
> The expected result is the PDF in a variable ready for an
>   .extractText()
>
> I'm new at python and I would appreciate any help

Comment: To answer your coding question: You are asking requests to decode binary data (the PDF) to text. PDF files are not text files, don’t do that. Use `response.content` to access just the binary data.

Comment: Next, PdfFileReader does not actually take a binary value. It wants a *stream*, a file-like object. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests/13137873#13137873) on how you get requests to give you a stream: `body.raw.decode_content = True` then `pdf_obj = pfr.PdfFileReader(body.raw)`.

Comment: Ah, but that won’t work either because [the documentation tells us the stream must support seeking](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html). So use my “image” answer to copy the PDF stream to a [spooled temporary file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), then *without closing the temporary file object*, seek back to 0 then pass it to the PdfFileReader object.

Comment: Thank you really much. I come from R and I didn't know the "file-like" category. I could finally get the text from the PDF thanks to your help.

Comment: Closing as dupe of the newer report, as it contains screenshots...

Comment: I removed the status tag since it was closed as a duplicate.