# Can't post a new question using guided mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

I have attached screenshots of the question page I see after going through the various steps of the Ask Question Wizard (guided mode).

Why is the 'Post Your Question' button greyed out here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have added another screenshot to make everything clear. I don't see how this is an exact duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Yes, it's related and I have notified admins. Stay tuned for an update :) (I've swapped the dupe target to this as you included screenshots!)

Comment: Dev here. We’re investigating. We’ll come back here with updates.

Comment: The older question doesn’t appear in the Linked list. Here it is for reference: [“Post your Question” is not available for clicking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386577/4642212).

Comment: We think we figured it out. Pushing a fix now.

Comment: This should be fixed. I'll come back to this in the AM with an explanation as an answer and update status after we do a full retro.

Comment: @JonChan Did tag suggestions break? See [Unable to post a question because tags won't display in drop down menu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386583/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon The thing that caused this bug was due to some fixes that went out a few hours ago. The [other bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386583/unable-to-post-a-question-because-tags-wont-display-in-drop-down-menu) you reported is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386395/not-seeing-formatting-toolbar-on-ask-question-screen) which happened before the cause of the one reported here (seems intermittent). I believe they're separate issues, but I'll investigate what's going there too. Will update in the other reports.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Why is Post your Question button greyed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330187/289905).

Comment: _"The thing that caused this bug was due to some fixes that went out a few hours ago. "_ Guys. Seriously. **Testing.** We provide your content for free; we are not also your free testers!

Comment: I'm still having this issue 6/28 11:30 ET

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Isn't that how Software is developed nowadays?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Software is cobbled together nowadays. That has nothing to do with *developed*.

Answer (score 8):

This particular issue has been resolved. One of the buttons in the navigation was causing the question form to be submitted before it should have been. This triggered validation prematurely for some users and disabled the correct submit button by the time you entered the review step.

We've fixed it by preventing event propagation for that button. We've also incorporated this scenario into our existing test suite so it won't happen in future releases.

Comment: Can you indicate if that fix is part of rev 2019.6.28.34163 or if we're waiting for an higher rev? Asking because of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330221/158100

Comment: This [might still be a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386693/6296561)

Comment: The issue is still, my colleague today couldn't post his question, the button was disabled. He has to navigate to one of previous step and then back to last, then button become enabled and he could click it.

Comment: Scratch that, [this is still most likely still a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387625/post-your-question-greyed-out).

Comment: Looking back into this.

Comment: This is still a problem.

Comment: still greyed out 10/17/19

Answer (score -1):

This is still a problem 06/08/2020

Comment: Perhaps post a new bug, and link this one. Since this one has been status-completed, and it's so long ago, I think this deserves an entirely new post to get it the attention it deserves (and it didn't get a reply after the comments in September and October last year)

Comment: surprisingly it work for me after deleting current draft,
than i created new one and had the same issue,
then after browser refresh it worked and i was able to post the question